# Has numerosity-preserving functions between structures been studied before?

Tags: reference-request, model-theory

Isomorphisms are bijective functions between structures that preserve the constants, relations, and functions of the structure. I wonder, has a notion of "strong isomorphism" between structures been studied before in the mathematical literature? By strong isomorphism, I mean a numerosity-preserving function between structures that preserve the constants, relations, and functions of the structure. So, for example, the structures $(\mathbb{N};<)$ and $(\mathbb{N}^+;<)$, where $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^+$ represent the set of nonnegative and positive integers respectively, are isomorphic but not strongly isomorphic, because they do not have the same numerosity, as $\mathbb{N}^+$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Basically, I am asking if numerosity-preserving functions have been studied.

Comment: What do you mean by "numerosity?" That's not a standard term.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I mean, a notion of size of sets that is finer than cardinality. That notion respects Euclid's notion of "the whole is greater than the part". Finite cardinalities are the same as finite numerosities, but in the case of infinite sets, numerosities are strictly finer than cardinalities.

Comment: Are numerosities linearly ordered? How do the numerosities of the even vs. odd integers compare? This needs to be a lot more precise.

Comment: Numerosity is not a mathematical word, what does it mean here? What if they are entirely different sets? This strikes me as not useful.

Comment: For example, is $\mathbb N$ more or less numerous than $\{1\}\times \mathbb N?$

Comment: In any event, without a definition of "more numerous," it is undefined.

Comment: The key failing I can see is that the composition of strong isomorphisms isn't a strong isomorphism. That makes it nearly completely useless for understanding a structure.